# Adding cells to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm calling the below 2 function once per Cell in a table with over 135 columns and over 200 rows (that is `134*200 = 26800` times, I'm not running the functions on the first column).

I would like to optimize the functions as much as possible.  Do you have any suggestions on how to do that, if it even possible?

```
this.addBodyCellFunction = function(row, index, func, params) {
    var cell = $(document.getElementById("table_row_" + row +"_col_" +index));
    cell.click(function() {
        func.apply(this, params);
    });
    cell.css("cursor", "pointer");
};

this.addBodyCellTooltip = function(row, index, text) {
    var cell = $(document.getElementById("table_row_" + row +"_col_" +index));
    cell.attr("title", text);
};
```

Comment: you could optimize by removing jquery?

Comment: Use delegation + stylesheet instead of `cell.css`.

Comment: Unless you're going to sort the rows and you need to fetch by its original location, you don't need to assign such specific IDs to every column. Just select the table, and use the `.rows` collection on the `table` and the `cells` collection on the `row`... like: `document.getElemntById("my_table").rows[1].cells[3]`

Comment: And in general, ditching jQuery when convenient will greatly improve performance. Like `cell.setAttribute("title", text)`.

Comment: could you post some more source code or better, jsfiddle / jsbin example ? I agree with @Karl-AndréGagnon, cell.css should be done by using css instead of using jquery for this purpose.

Comment: this might be not a actual solution, but you can take a look to https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki plugin. Works really good with big data on tables, and cells

Comment: So every row click needs to call a separate function with a separate set of parameters?

Answer (score 1):

There a few options here, for instance you don't need to use Jquery as much as you are using. This will optimize greatly all of your code.
You can simply use JavaScript commands related to table with `document.getElementById("table").rows[].cell[]`
 which is very simple and works very nicely and fast. By doing that there  is no need to assign ID's to everything on the table, as you probably are doing now.

Comment: Just because the question missuses jQuery, that is no reason to shift to raw Javascript. A delegated event will do a much better job (which is much harder to write in raw javascript).

Comment: Very true. That would be indeed a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

So, the big one looks like it would switching to one delegate instead of binding a listener to every cell.

Assuming that each `$(document.getElementById("table_row_" + row +"_col_" +index))` represents a cell, this should work fine:

```
$(table).on('td', 'click', function(){func.apply(this, params);})
```

As to

```
var cell = $(document.getElementById("table_row_" + row +"_col_" +index));
cell.attr("title", text);
```

You can get rid of the `$` and use plain JS:

```
// you can also use the document.getElementById("table").rows[].cell[]
// method that Luan suggested.
var cell = document.getElementById("table_row_" + row +"_col_" +index);
cell.setAttribute('title', text)
```